# how to stop DEBUG message in tomcat's log file

Tags: tomcat, logging, block, message

I am using a Spring RESTful webservice application with Tomcat Server. But due to excess log messages causes it hampers performance. Could please anybody help how to stop excess DEBUG message in tomcat's log file?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you mention which webservice you are running and to show an example of the log (not as screenshot, just copy/paste and the select **format as code** in the editor (the button with { } ). Note that you can [edit] your question

Comment: Most probably you need to configure your logging library that is used by your webapp .... What logging library do you use now and what is their configuration ?

Comment: I am using  "commons-logging -1.2.jar"... due to excess DEGUB message. it  is harm to my application.i need to stop  all  spring framework  debug message to stop in TOMCAT  log  file.  only error message to show....I am using  spring REST